# jQuery .fadeIn() working but .slideDown() and .animate() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate, slidedown

I'm trying to set up a website that loads pages through ajax calls replacing the current contents of  with the ajax response. I'm putting a # and a page name at the end of my URLs so that people can book mark pages.

- www.examplesite.com#home
- www.examplesite.com#examples
- www.examplesite.com#examples/example1
- www.examplesite.com#examples/example2

I'm new to jQuery and to a lesser extent JavaScript but I'm trying to get a different page animation when I go to a page that is stored in a sub folder. fadeIn() works fine on both pages and pages in sub-folders however I can't get .slideDown() or .animate() to work at all. Here is an extract from my code:

```
<script>
//All pages are stored in a folder called 'pages' or a subfolder of 'pages'
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myUrl = $(location).attr('href');
        var noPage = myUrl.indexOf('#');
        if(noPage == -1) {
            location.hash = 'home';
        }
        window.onhashchange = function() {
            pageChange();
        }
        function pageChange() {
            var myUrl = $(location).attr('href');
            var page = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf('#') + 1, myUrl.length);
            $.get('pages/' + page + '.html', function(pageHtml) {
                if (page.indexOf('/') != -1) {
                    $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).slideDown(400);
                } else {
                    $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).fadeIn(400);
                }
            }); 
        };
        pageChange();
    });
</script>
```

If I'm approaching this from completely the wrong direction and that's why it's not working do feel free to point me in the correct direction by giving me an example of how it should work.

Comment: This will not solve your problem but you can reduce your code by replacing $(location).attr('href');  var page = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf('#') + 1, myUrl.length);with page  = location.hash.substring(1);

Comment: Would you mind setting up a Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Bob Does the content load and are you able to see it when u remove the .hide() thing ?

Comment: @MevinBabu yeah I've tried removing the .hide() but that didn't seem to help, and yes the content loads fine. I'm going to try and setup a jsfiddle, hopefully that will help

Comment: @Bob You should reverse your html and hide methods.  $('.main').html(pageHtml).hide().slideDown(400);

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte thanks but again it has had no effect, still works with fadeIn but not with SlideDown.

Comment: I am trying to get a fiddle to work but to be honest I'm having problems just getting an ajax call to work properly so I'm not overly hopeful I'll be able to adapt the above.

Comment: @Bob maybe something in the CSS must be blocking it ?  try disabling the CSS for the `main` class and try again ?

Comment: yes :) min-height, figured it out last night but stack overflow wouldn't let me post an answer to my own question until today. If you want you can leave that as an answer rather than a comment and I'll mark it at the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

I was using the css min-height property with a couple of my divs so that the page would expand automatically with the content if there was a lot on the page. If I remove the min-height property and replace it with a fixed height .slideDown() works fine.

Here are some links for more info if anyone else has the same issue:
http://www.only10types.com/2011/09/jquery-slidedown-doesnt-work-on.html 
[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Around_The_Minimum_Height_Glitch](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Around_The_Minimum_Height_Glitch)

Answer (score 0):

I would take this...

```
            if (page.indexOf('/') != -1) {
                $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).slideDown(400);
            } else {
                $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).fadeIn(400);
            }
```

And rearrange it to make sure your if statement is correct

```
            if (page.indexOf('/') != -1) {
                $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).fadeIn(400);
            } else {
                $('.main').hide().html(pageHtml).slideDown(400);
            }
```

If it now slides instead of fades, the if statement is corrupt

Comment: nope afraid not, my page still updates with either of the above but the slideDown animation just doesn't seem to want to kick in  :(

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? Does this work ?

```
 var main_div=$('.main');
 main_div.hide();

 $.get('pages/' + page + '.html', function(pageHtml) {
                if (page.indexOf('/') != -1) {
                    main_div.html(pageHtml)
                } else {
                    main_div.html(pageHtml)
                }
            });

 main_div.slideDown(400);
```

Comment: Afraid not, the page loads but there is no animation. It does work if I change the .slideDown(400) to .fadeIn(400) though...

Answer (score 0):

maybe something in the CSS must be blocking it ? try disabling the CSS for the `main` class and try again ?